# Is it correct to use UIView.AccessibilityValue or AccessibilityIdentifier property to store some custom data in ios xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, uiview, xamarin.ios

My questions are

- 1) Whether or not i can use
  AccessibilityValue/AccessibilityIdentifier property to identify or
  track the controls (Subviews).(Looping through subviews and find a
  particular control with the AccessibilityValue/Identifier)
- 2) When i am setting these properties to a certain value, can these
  values conflict with any of system generated values (if any)?
- 3) Can i use them to store some data say if i want to display a list
  of users (storing user id in AccessibliltyValue/Identifier in the
  subviews), to be shown in scrollview(when not using tableviews to
  display them)
- 4) Last but not the least, is it a good practice to do the stuff in 1
  and 3 using these properties .

Here's the code segment just for a ref.

```
    private void GenerateUI(){
       UIView containerView = new UIView( new RectangleF(0,0,View.Frame.Width,View.Frame.Height));
       View.AddSubview(containerView);

       var leaderBoardButton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
                leaderBoardButton.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 200, 220, 40);
                leaderBoardButton.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
                leaderBoardButton.Layer.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
                leaderBoardButton.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.ColorWithAlpha (0.6f).CGColor;
                leaderBoardButton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
                leaderBoardButton.SetTitle("Leaderboard", UIControlState.Normal);
                leaderBoardButton.SetTitleColor (UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
                leaderBoardButton.AccessibilityValue= "leaderboardButton";
                leaderBoardButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
                    somefunction();
                };

      containerView.Add(leaderBoardButton)


       var communityButton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
                communityButton.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 240, 220, 40);
                communityButton.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.ColorWithAlpha (0.6f).CGColor;
                communityButton.Layer.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
                communityButton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
                communityButton.SetTitle("Community", UIControlState.Normal);
                communityButton.SetTitleColor (UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
                communityButton.AccessibilityValue= "communityButton";
                communityButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
                    //VirtualMentorDemo2ViewController vdc = (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as   AppDelegate).StoryBoard.InstantiateViewController("VirtualMentorDemo2ViewController") as VirtualMentorDemo2ViewController;
                    //NavController.PushViewController(vdc, false);
                    //SidebarController.CloseMenu();
                };

    containerView.Add(communityButton);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to use the accessibility properties for storing extra metadata.   Those ones are used by the accessibility system to provide information to users that might have turned it on.

If you want to tag items, you can use the "Tag" property in a UIView for this purpose.

Comment: Can you explain the first 2 lines, bit more in detail. Basically how and when the accessibility system accesses it and uses those props ?